# Which binary matrices can be filled with numbers such that all rows and columns sum up to $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

Is there anything known about which binary (square) matrices allow to be filled up with non-negative real numbers (in the non-zero positions) such that each row and each column sums up to one?  E.g. for $$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ this is not possible, even though there are no all-zero rows or columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want rows to sum to one, that is a Markov matrix (although wikipedia calls it a Stochastic matrix). If you want both rows and columns, it is called a doubly stochastic Markov matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly those matrices with non-zero permanent.

**Proof:** if $\text{perm}(M)>0$ then there exists $\sigma\in{\cal S}_n$ such that $\prod_i a_{i\sigma(i)}=1$ and putting $1$s at all positions $(i,\sigma(i))$ yields a (permutation) matrix where each row and column sums up to $1$.

On the other side, if there is some $M$ with $n_{ij}>0$ only if $m_{ij}=1$ where each row and column sums up to $1$, fix $i,j$ with $n_{1j}>0$.  Then cut out the $i$th row and $j$ column, name the result $N$ and conclude by some induction argument that there exists $\tau\in{\cal S}_{n-1}$ such that $\prod_i n_{i\sigma'(i)}=1$.  So $$\sigma'(i'):=\begin{cases}\tau(i')&i'<i\\j&i'=i\\\tau(i'-1)&\text{else}\end{cases}$$ satisfies the requirement $m_{i\sigma(i)}=1$ for all $i$.